# Printing different variables using Timer and TimerTask in java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I've got a small problem concerning printing a sentence using a Timer. I know the procedure of extending TimerTask and overriding the run method but here I can print a static sentence. 
But in my case I have to print a list of songs (from an array) and a list of artists (from an array) in different time periods.

For example I have 3 songs: the first one has 3 minutes, the second one has 2.5 minutes, and the third one has 5 minutes. The output should be the following:

Song One by Artist One is playing...
(after 3 minutes)
Song Two by Artist Two is playing...
(after 2.5 minutes)
Song Three by Artist Three is playing...
(after 5 minutes)
Program stops.

The code I have so far is this:

Main Class:

```
package test;

import java.util.Timer;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");



    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread();
        int dur = t.getDurations()[i];
        timer.schedule(t, 0, dur);
    }


}
}
```

Class extending the TimerTask:

```
package test;

import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
*
* @author GraphPixel
*/
public class Thread extends TimerTask {
String[] song_list = { "Song One", "Song Two", "Song Three" };
String[] artist_list = { "Artist One", "Artist Two", "Artist Three" };
int[] durations = { 2000, 1500, 2500 };

public int[] getDurations() {
    return durations;
}

public String[] getSong_list() {
    return song_list;
}

public String[] getArtist_list() {
    return artist_list;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
        System.out.println(song_list[i] + " played by " + artist_list[i]);
        i++;
    cancel();
}

}
```

When I run the program I get all the three sentences printed at the same time, no time difference between them

Answer (score 0):

You are scheduling same Thread multiple times. So once it is already scheduled, on second iteration in the loop, when code tries to schedule it again, you get `IllegalStateException`

You need to create separate Thread objects in loop

```
import java.util.Timer;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");        

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread();
        timer.schedule(t, 0, t.getDurations()[i]);
    }    
  }
}
```